# How to take button at the center of the UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am generating multiple buttons in my scrollview, A scroll view that has constrains at main.storyboard so it's width changes on different iphones. and i can't make my buttons to the center. Here is my code.

```
@synthesize table,scroll;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.  
img = @[@"Shirley-Stevens.jpg"];

NSUInteger i;
int buttonWidth=50;
int buttonHeight=50;
int space = 50;
//    int xCoord= 100;// (scroll.frame.size.width/2) - buttonWidth - space;
//    int Xcoord2= 200;//(scroll.frame.size.width/2) + buttonWidth + space;

int xCoord = (scroll.contentSize.width/2) + buttonWidth + space + buttonWidth + space;
int Xcoord2= (scroll.contentSize.width/2) + buttonWidth + space;
int yCoord=0;
int buffer = 10;
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[img objectAtIndex:0]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    aButton.frame     = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight );
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scroll addSubview:aButton];

    UIButton *bButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [bButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[img objectAtIndex:0]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    bButton.frame     = CGRectMake(Xcoord2, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight );
    [bButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scroll addSubview:bButton];

    yCoord += buttonHeight + buffer;
}
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, yCoord)];
}

- (IBAction)whatever:(UIButton *)sender {
NSLog(@"Button");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my Code Now that works fine, Basically the problem is, viewDidLoad called before the parameters of scrollview updates. So the best method to practice scrollview is viewDidAppear.

```
@synthesize table,scroll;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
img = @[@"Shirley-Stevens.jpg",
         @"Shirley-Stevens.jpg"];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
NSUInteger i;
int buttonWidth=50;
int buttonHeight=50;
int space = 50;
int xCoord  = (scroll.frame.size.width/2) - buttonWidth - space;
int Xcoord2 = (scroll.frame.size.width/2) + space;
int yCoord=0;
int buffer = 10;
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[img objectAtIndex:0]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    aButton.frame     = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight );
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scroll addSubview:aButton];

    UIButton *bButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [bButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[img objectAtIndex:0]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    bButton.frame     = CGRectMake(Xcoord2, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight );
    [bButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scroll addSubview:bButton];

    yCoord += buttonHeight + buffer;
}
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, yCoord)];
}


- (IBAction)whatever:(UIButton *)sender {
NSLog(@"Button");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `center` point of `UIButton` along with `frame`.

For example: Set the center point at width/2 & height/2 of `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make changes only below two line  -

Assume that you need two button in center with space gap in between.

```
int xCoord = (scroll.contentSize.width/2) - (space/2) - buttonWidth;
int Xcoord2= (scroll.contentSize.width/2)  + (space/2);
```

Hope this will help you.